# How the compiler interprets preincrement/decrement and postincrement/decrement

Tags: c++, return-value, postfix-operator, prefix-operator

When someone asks about the difference between post-increment/decrement and pre-increment/decrement, the response is usually that the prefix versions add one to the variable and return the new value of the variable whereas the postfix versions add one to the variable and return the old value.

While messing around, I found out that all of these lines are legal:

```
int i = 1;
++i;
++++++++++++++i;
(++++++++++++++i)++;
(++++++(++++(++i)))++;
------i;
--++++--++----++i;
i+=++++++++++++++i+i++-i--;
```

But none of the following lines are legal:

```
i++++;
++i++;
--i--;
```

If I assume that the prefix versions return by reference, this all makes sense (even the last example because postfix has higher precedence than prefix).

Is the assumption/realization that the prefix versions return a reference and the postfix versions return a value correct? Are there any other subtle behavior differences that I don't know about for the pre/post inc/decrement operators?

Comment: You possibly don't know how they're implemented by gcc on an UltraSPARC 9 architecture. You certainly wouldn't know how often they've been used in code, or the date they were invented. There are, perhaps, a range of subtleties surrounding their C++ semantics when overloaded that you aren't aware of. Is there some kind of bounding box you can put around this question to make it more readily answerable?

Comment: @Kerrek not what again? @Mercelo see if that's better.

Comment: @Seth: A question about mixing huge number of pluses and minuses and about precedence rules and sequence points comes up about every three to five days on SO... just search a bit if you're curious, but I wonder why this would ever be a genuine concern.

Comment: just think how much better the world would be if these abominable things had never been invented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++, the prefix increment/decrement expressions "return" lvalues and the postfix versions return rvalues. In C both forms return rvalues.

However, be aware that the behavior is undefined if you try to writing to a variable more than once between two sequence points. So the distinction doesn't really matter anyway.

Answer (score 2):

> All this is legal:

No, it isn't legal. Writing the variable more than once in that way is Undefined Behaviour. It's syntactically correct, and it'll compile, but it sure isn't legal.

Comment: Pedant++: Someone once argued that everything is *legal* (since it's not outlawed), it's just not *valid*. Would that be worth extra rep?

Comment: @Kerrek SB: No. More importantly, just look at how much rep I have. You think I need one more upvote? :P

Answer (score 0):

One that comes to mind is the common coding error of using a variable at least twice in the same statement, with at least one instance applying a pre/post increment:

```
i = i++;
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is the assumption/realization that the
>   prefix versions return a reference and
>   the postfix versions return a value
>   correct

No. Why would you assume that? It's a built in operator, and compiler can implement it as it wishes.

Your "legal" examples may compile, but will produce undefined behavior because you read and write into the same variable multiple times without a sequence point.

Comment: The compiler can't -- there is a standard behind it. The standard specifies that ++i is a lvalue.

Comment: @forcey - not in C, and anyway - it doesn't matter because it's not a reference, it's an lvalue. If the standard would say "++i returns a reference" then the assumption would be correct.